# Custom wp_link_pages for paginated posts | Next page randomly

Tags: pagination, wp-link-pages

Does anyone know if it's possible to change `wp_link_pages`,
I want to change the order of the pages
Example :
i have an Post consisting of 5 pages
i want when you click on "Next page", it takes you to a random page of the five pages that we have in the article. without repeat

Any ideas/help greatly appreciated, S.

Comment: What do you mean by, you have a post containing 5 pages? how can a post contain pages exactly?

Comment: @Buttered_Toast by adding <!--nextpage--> 5 time in a single post you get one post with 5 pages right ?

Comment: Would it be possible to show an example? maybe add your code that you have done so far, even provide a link to what you are working on. If it's local, provide us with a way to replicate what you currently have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the [`wp_link_pages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_link_pages/) function is an option, but randomizing either the page numbers or page links may be detrimental to the user's experience as he's expecting a normal page link structure while noticing random page numbers, e.g. in the post's URL.

However, there exists a [`content_pagination`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/content_pagination/) filter that lets you alter the post's `$pages` array. Simply [shuffling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) this array would suffice, however, this does neither guarantee a static page order nor does it exclude the possibility of page repetition, as the shuffle is executed on each page load.

You could solve both these problems by using [`array_multisort()`](https://www.php.net/array_multisort) in combination with [`mt_srand()`](https://www.php.net/mt_srand), as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6557868/1418958), and seed the random number generator with e.g. the post's ID—but then, every user is served the same (pseudo-random) page order, and one could argue what's the use of shuffling the pages at all.

You could mix in the user ID (if any) in the seed, e.g. by multiplying the post ID with the user ID, to increase the chances of giving each registered user their "own" static page order that varies across posts. In the end, it really depends on what you want, and how far you are willing to go with it.

Code example (seeded with post ID):

```
function shuffle_pages( array $pages, WP_Post $post ): array {
    mt_srand( $post->ID );
    $order = array_map( function ( $val ) { return mt_rand(); }, range( 1, count( $pages ) ) );
    array_multisort( $order, $pages );
    return $pages;
}
add_filter( 'content_pagination', 'shuffle_pages', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Sorry for this late reply, i've test Code example that you suggested, 

But it didn't work,
function.php: https://i.imgur.com/p3bvhHh.png

Please check if i used it properly?
or i should I change anything wp-links() ?

Comment: My apologies, I had not tested my code and made two type declaration errors. I have now fixed them and the code runs correctly on my end.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work. i think she is missing something ...
Here is the result link:  https://tastyandhealthy.net/believing-these-10-myths-about-laptops-keeps-you-from-growing/
I appreciate your effort very much. 

Comment: content.php > wp_link_pages code : https://i.imgur.com/LxWTW5q.png
function.php > https://i.imgur.com/tSTh9YZ.png
result video : http://recordit.co/M8fOvjUDTC

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: PHP 7.3 (ea-php73)

Comment: is there any update please?

Comment: I sent you a private message, and will report back here once we resolve the issue.

Comment: Problem solved, code was working, but we made some changes to satisfy the use case.

Comment: Thank you @Cas for your help and support